# How do I train the Python SpeechRecognition 2.1.1 Library

Tags: python, machine-learning, speech-recognition, text-analysis

I am just getting started in speech recognition and was wondering what the general process was for training the SpeechRecognition library from Python:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

I know basic machine learning techniques and basic text analytics, but I am not sure how to apply this to train sound data. (my end result would resemble the typical speech typing from phones where if you change the speech analyzer result often enough, it will "remember" the user preference).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That speech recognition library is using Google's speech recognition engine so there is no particular provision for training at the user end. Your sound data goes to Google (in digest form). If you get a dedicated API (as that documentation page suggests) it is possible Google will be building a user-specific profile on your voice and will gain statistical quality over time based on this, but that is not something that would be stored or written at your end.

Any further questions or unaddressed elements of your question, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question and I will accept it as the solution when the min time passes!

Comment: On another note, is there any Python library that will let me do this? This particular library gives me the necessary speed of "translation" and pretty good accuracy. But I would love if I could somehow train it (for example "ABCDFG" is always outputted as "ABCDEFG" because of the trailing "ee" sound of "D"

Comment: Have you tried the Google version to see if it gets that correct? I worked on voice recognition for a couple years and Google is so far beyond what we used to think was possible that one could argue they must be using witchcraft. If you want to experiment with training I'd recommend using the library above and trying to add your own process at the digest process step, and using scikit-learn (python library) to learn various transformations. This allows you to continue to pass the boring stuff to Google. Warning: prepare to spend a lot of time reading up on Markov Chains :)

Comment: Hmm... or alternately you could work with the returned transcription as a guide to a saved copy of the audio to help you choose refining targets. Then if you spot anticipated errors you could alter the problem section and resubmit it silently behind the scenes! Again, using scikit-learn for the learning part would probably work well, it's a gret library.

Comment: @user947659 - gentle reminder to select an answer when convenient

Comment: Selected :)...Yup I tried the google version too, I think it uses the latest Chrome version so this is the closest I can get. I was thinking about doing what you suggested and adding my own process after the google translate step.